# array_splice() is not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, array-splice

Some help please with this thing that was confused me about the correct use of `array_splice();`
When i copy literally the following code  from the php.net website, that appears as follow:

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 2);
// $input is now array("red", "green")
```

But on my localhost, the result is not as shown in the website example. I got this:

```
Array ( [0] => blue [1] => yellow )
```

What happens here?

Resource http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: [Works for me](https://3v4l.org/hDeYY)

Comment: I have been tested the same code on  [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org)  but the result is not as the expected in php.net.

Comment: https://3v4l.org/pMBXD

Comment: please check again you might be doing some more stuffs.

Comment: That's right @CharlotteDunois I understend now the correct use of this function. Thank you, thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. The return array will contain removed elements, i.e. `( "red", "green" )`. The original array will be modified to contain the elements which were not removed, i.e. `( "blue", "yellow" )`.

Comment: Well, then that is a documentation problem of [php.net](http://php.net)? if so, then all examples are wrong!!

Comment: @user5782629 No, the return value of `array_splice` contains the removed elements. `$input` has the not removed ones.